# getQueryVariable problems, and questions

Tags: javascript

This script is plaguing me, No matter what I do it is showing the top document.write line as being wrong. and it fails at that point. Am hoping someone could help me
Head

```
function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
   var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
   var vars = query.split("&");
   for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
           var pair = vars[i].split("=");
           if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
   }
   return(false);
}
</script>
```

Body

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
<!--

if (getQueryVariable("catid")= "Merchandise") {
document.write('<div id='div-gpt-ad-1403912225717-2'><script type='text/javascript'>googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1403912225717-2'); });</script></div>')
document.write('<div id='div-gpt-ad-1403912225717-2'><script type='text/javascript'>googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1403912225717-3'); });</script></div>')
} else if (getQueryVariable("catid")= "Automotive") {
document.write('<div id='div-gpt-ad-1403912225717-2'><script type='text/javascript'>googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1403910107020-2'); });</script></div>')
document.write('<div id='div-gpt-ad-1403912225717-2'><script type='text/javascript'>googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1403910107020-3'); });</script></div>')
} else if (getQueryVariable("catid")= "Yard Sales") 
document.write('<div id='div-gpt-ad-1403912225717-2'><script type='text/javascript'>googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1403912225717-2'); });</script></div>')
document.write('<div id='div-gpt-ad-1403912225717-2'><script type='text/javascript'>googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1403912225717-3'); });</script></div>')
} else if (getQueryVariable("catid")= "Public Notices") {
document.write('<div id='div-gpt-ad-1403912225717-2'><script type='text/javascript'>googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1403910107020-2'); });</script></div>')
document.write('<div id='div-gpt-ad-1403912225717-2'><script type='text/javascript'>googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1403910107020-3'); });</script></div>')
} else if (getQueryVariable("catid")= "Services") {
document.write('<div id='div-gpt-ad-1403912225717-2'><script type='text/javascript'>googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1403910107020-2'); });</script></div>')
document.write('<div id='div-gpt-ad-1403912225717-2'><script type='text/javascript'>googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1403910107020-3'); });</script></div>')
} else if (getQueryVariable("catid")= "Real Estate for Sale") {
document.write('<div id='div-gpt-ad-1403912225717-2'><script type='text/javascript'>googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1403913003830-2'); });</script></div>')
document.write('<div id='div-gpt-ad-1403912225717-2'><script type='text/javascript'>googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1403913003830-3'); });</script></div>')
} else {
document.write('<div id='div-gpt-ad-1403912225717-2'><script type='text/javascript'>googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1403911366201-2'); });</script></div>')
document.write('<div id='div-gpt-ad-1403912225717-2'><script type='text/javascript'>googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1403911366201-3'); });</script></div>')
}
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: The color coding should make it obvious. You are closing quotes you didn't want to close: `document.write('<div id='div-gpt-ad-1403`. Add double quotes on the outside.

Answer (score 0):

Properly use the string combination (use double quotes inside single quote):

```
document.write('<div id="div-gpt-ad-1403912225717-2"><script type="text/javascript">googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display("div-gpt-ad-1403912225717-2"); });</script></div>')
```

Comment: Thanks, Made those changes but still getting this on screen when i run the page; 
     at 
') document.write('') } else if (getQueryVariable("catid")= "Automotive") {